# How to check in a Vue component if a user is authenticated in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, authentication, vue.js, vuex

As the title states, I'm a little confused how I would tackle a method in my Vue Component with if/else statement based on if the user is logged in and authenticated with Laravel's Auth facade. I'm making various Axios requests which I need to allow/disallow based on if user logged in.

I have VUEX setup and was thinking that I can use local storage somehow to have a state for ***isLoggedin*** for example that works with Laravel.  But I don't know if this is correct method, or secure and presumably Laravel is already storing it's authentication.  So can I just access that direct in Vue?

Some unclean solutions here that I don't think are the best -
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/hide-button-if-user-is-logged-with-laravel-and-vuejs

I can not find any examples for this :(

Comment: Why don't you use OAuth2 for authentication and check if the user is authenticated on each request ?

Comment: I guess I could, but that's a little advanced for my purposes and takes learning.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Usually from your controller, you pass the authenticated user object into the view which will then be stored in a javascript variable

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('index', [
        'auth_user' => Auth::user()
    ]);
}
```

You will know if a user is authenticated if it returns an object or null where null means no user is authenticated.

In your blade, assign the `auth_user` into a javascript variable:

```
<script>
    window.auth_user = {!! json_encode($auth_user); !!};
</script>
```

your vuex store object should atleast look like this:

```
{
    state: {
        user: null
    },
    mutations: {
        setAuthUser(state, user) {
            state.user = user;
        }
    },
    getters: {
        isLoggedIn(state) {
            return state.user !== null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your Vue root component, get the `auth_user` and save it into the store:

```
<script>
    export default {

        mounted() {
            this.$store.commit('setAuthUser', window.auth_user);
        }

    }
</script>
```

You now basically have a `getter` called `this.$store.getters.isLoggedIn` that you can use in your application for checking if a user is currently logged in.

e.g:

Comment: Working good.  For reference I had to use instead
`window.auth_user = {!! json_encode($auth_user) !!};`
Also, had to insert the blade script before the Vue root master component (header not footer in my case)

Comment: But what if the client refresh his page? Then he will loose the state. Is there a solution for?

Comment: The page will definitely lose whatever state it previously had after refreshing, but in this case it doesn't matter. The code above will always make sure that you have `user` in your `store` even after you have refreshed the page since the code will just run again.

Comment: Sorry for late question. What if user was logged out, but dont refresh page? For example if session ends.

Comment: @raskalbass you need to implement a way to detect that from the front end side. One way is to create an interval which checks the session every XX seconds/minutes. An another way is to add a catch block to your ajax request which will check if the error is related to expired session.

Comment: Is this secure? @JulianPaoloDayag

Comment: @MayankDudakiya I'm not sure what you meant by secure. Technically speaking, nothing is secure in the front-end side. This method only exposes the user via a global javascript variable to the rendered html output which you can then access inside your Vue application.

As long as you don't include any sensitive information into the user object like password, card credentials, etc... then you're just going to be fine.

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag We are passing non-sensitive information so it's secure. I don't think so any requirement of passing any credentials via this method. If just pass user ID then we can get any information related to the user via API. What's say?

Comment: you can also pass only the user id if that's what you want. It really is up to you what you pass into the variable.

Answer (score 4):

Use axios interceptors. You intercept the access denied http response code and then act accordingly.

```
window.axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    return response;
}, function (error) {
    if (419 === error.response.status) {
         location.reload();
    } else {
        //Something else you want to do or do nothing
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Putting a script within blade file will throw Vue Warning. Let me answer "How to check in a Vue component if a user is authenticated in Laravel" and leave you with your Vuex complexity. Also this method is simpler.

So, in your controller:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('index')->with('auth_user',  auth()->user());
}
```

In your blade(main.blade.php):

```
<div class="container">
    <example-component :auth_user='@json($auth_user)'></example-component>
</div>
```

In your vue-component, get your props(ExampleComponent.vue):

```
<script>
export default {

  props: ['auth_user'],

  created () {
    console.log(this.auth_user)

  }
}
</script>
```

Returns null if user is not logged in

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with laravel 7+
and it doesn't need to send Auth::user() via controller
Just call it from your laravel blade template file like below

**your-template-name.blade.php**

```
@if (Auth::check())
    <script>window.authUser={!! json_encode(Auth::user()); !!};</script>
@else
    <script>window.authUser=null;</script>
@endif
```

**inside YourComponent.vue, store authUser like this:**

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                authUser: window.authUser
            }
        },

        created() {
            console.log(this.authUser);
        },

        methods: {
            yourMethodName() {
                console.log(this.authUser);
            }
        }
    }
<script>
```