# Why can I not read Vuex store on "Mounted" component in a Vue component?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

This will result in *false* on the *mounted* hook.

But it's set to *true* and will also return true on a method as expected, or computed property or directly even on a `v-if=""` statement!

```
this.$store.getters.getIsLoggedIn
```

I'd like to use the state to perform action upon mounting the component, but am I to presume that for some reason the state is not readable at this stage?  What am I not understanding about Vuex?

Comment: this might not be enough context to answer the question

Comment: could you provide the main.js ?

Comment: The Vuex state is readable in the mounted hook. At which times are you observing it's value is *true* – outside of the mounted hook? It could be initially *false* (during mounted) but then changed to *true* after mounting. You need to carefully debug it at different stages of the component lifecycle to confirm its value is what you expect at that time. We can't help you much beyond guessing what the issue could be without a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry there's no example here, it's quite complicated and is a Laravel user object that's setting the variable in this manner - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51329297/how-to-check-in-a-vue-component-if-a-user-is-authenticated-in-laravel?noredirect=1#comment91038875_51329297

So, it is a debugging issue I think.  It's good to have confirmation that the Vuex state is readable in the mounted hook which helps narrow down.